# Hibernate com vários bancos de dados na mesma aplicação

Tags: java, hibernate

Um sistema usa para cada cliente um banco de dados separado, digamos que eu terei 500 clientes, nesse caso no meu servidor de banco de dados teria 500 `data bases`, exemplo:

```
cliente1 

cliente2 

cliente3
```

Na configuração do Hibernate é gerado um `Factory` onde nessas configurações contém em qual banco o sistema vai conectar-se.

Vão existir 500 `Factory` na aplicação?

Comment: Você quer saber se vai ficar com 500 **instâcias** de **EntityManagerFactory**?

Comment: Estou usando somente o hibernate e não o JPA, numa mesma aplicação eu quero conectar digamos a 500 database do mysql, eu queria saber se tinha como criar apenas um Factory e a partir desse eu conectar aos 500 database

Comment: Eu não gostaria de criar um Factory para cada conexão com o database, isso vai detonar a memória do servidor!

Comment: Considere mostrar como está o seu código (configuração Hibernate para mais de um database e criação da sessão). Dica: você pode criar os contextos de acesso aos dados sob demanda e destruir quando inativo, então só terá 500 contextos se todos os clientes acessarem ao mesmo tempo. Se os 500 clientes simultaneamente conectados não compensam o investimento em infra, você pode reconsiderar sua arquitetura de banco de dados (outro tipo de separação que não por cliente e outros tipos de bancos de dados não relacionais).

Comment: Então podemos concluir que não dá para ter apenas um Factory e usá-lo para várias base de dados, e sim para cada base eu vou ter que da um factory = config.buildSessionFactory(); ou seja, é totalmente inviável no meu caso, lembrando que pode ter mais de 500 clientes!

Comment: Se quando você diz "Factory" você se refere a "SessionFactory" sim, é um para cada database. O SessionFactory mantém um pool de conexões para um determinado database. Você pode medir para saber previamente quanto precisará de memória e outros recursos de infra. 500 databases ou 500 conexões simultâneas em um servidor SQL pode custar mais do que 500 instâncias de SessionFactory.

Comment: Blz Caffe, depois vou fazer uma simulação e qualquer coisa posto o resultado aqui, valeww

Answer (score 1):

Temos uma situação semelhante no NHibernate (.NET) devido à arquitetura de nosso sistema, que utiliza um schema (database) para cada filial.

Neste caso, você pode utilizar um `SessionFactory` apenas, assumindo a responsabilidade de criar as conexões.

Para isso, você deve:

1) Criar uma classe herdada de `org.hibernate.connection.DriverConnectionProvider` (exemplo em C#):

```
internal class MeuDbConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
    protected override string ConnectionString {
        // To-Do: Aqui você deve retornar a String de conexão baseada em uma variável
        //        'static' (neste meu caso, chamei de "SessionManager") que provê a base em que vc está conectado no momento
        get { return SessionManager.CurrentDatabaseConnection.ConnectionString; }
    }
    public override System.Data.IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        // To-Do: Criar uma nova conexão MySql baseada na String de Conexao
        //        da "base corrente"
        (...)
        return novaConexao;
    }
}
```

2) Definir que o Hibernate utilize o seu ConnectionProvider para a criação de conexões.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .setProperty(Environment.CONNECTION_PROVIDER, "com.my.package.MeuDbConnectionProvider");
```

Dali em diante, o poder estará em suas mãos - utilizando apenas um `SessionFactory`.

Observações:

- Esta situação vale apenas para quando você estiver utilizando o mesmo dialeto para todas as conexões;
- Veja também [este link *(em inglês)*](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18406.html).

Comment: Qual seria a vantagem do AP em fazer isso? Em .Net, o ADO.NET mantém um pool de conexões - ele reaproveita uma conexão do pool quando você solicita uma nova; ele faz isso com base na string de conexão. Em Java, é o próprio Hibernate quem mantém o pool de conexões através de uma implementação interna da interface ConnectionProvider que você está sugerindo que seja substituída. Se você usar este seu design em Java (*"Criar uma nova conexão..."*), o que vai acontecer é que não haverá pool de conexões; a cada nova solicitação uma nova conexão será aberta e o custo será absurdamente alto.

Comment: @Caffé: O problema não é a conexão em si, e sim o objeto `ISessionFactory`. Esse objeto é extremamente custoso a ser criado e mantido (tempo e memória, respectivamente). Criar um `ISessionFactory` apenas por variar o `Schema` do banco de dados implica em um *overhead* desnecessário. Sobre a conexão ser mantida "aberta", isto não é verdade: o (N)Hibernate fecha a conexão quando esta não for mais necessária (desde que o objeto `ISession` tenha sido criado sem uma conexão pré-definida).

Comment: Não quero discutir longamente por aqui mas a pergunta do AP é importante e uma resposta como a sua pode desorientar quem chegar por aqui. Alguns dos seus enganos: ISessionFactory não é um objeto, é uma interface. Um SessionFactory em Java tem um motivo para ser custoso: abrir conexões com o banco de dados e gerenciar estas conexões é custoso - não existe outro "overhead". Por último, eu não afirmei nada "sobre a conexão ser mantida aberta" portanto não entendi o que você quis dizer. Uma sugestão: não responda pergunta de Java em .Net ignorando as importantes diferenças entre estas plataformas.

Comment: Só para constar, ainda estou utilizando um SessionFactory para cada conexão, ainda não fiz a simulação de 500 conexões para ver o consumo de memória (medo rsrrs). O esquema de 1 sessions factory para cada cliente está funcionando, se for necessário vou ter que aumentar a capacidade do servidor em termos de memória principalmente, até achar uma outra solução!